# Tesseract на Android

Tags: java, android, tesseract

Решил прикрутить Tesseract к проекту, перепробовал кучу примеров, например:

- http://www.codepool.biz/making-an-android-ocr-application-with-tesseract.html
- https://github.com/komamitsu/Android-OCRSample
- https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR

Везде выбивает ошибку при создании папки на ExternalStorage и соотв текст не распознает, в манифесте прописаны все пермишены. Как я могу без всяких траблов скопировать /tessdata/rus.traineddata из Assets на ExternalStorage?

Comment: Текст ошибок приведите, пожалуйста.

Comment: У вас Android 6?

Comment: @katso minsdk jellybean, а открывал приложение на эмуляторе 5.0 и на телефоне 4.4

Comment: Всем спасибо, чудом каким-то заработало само через время